# Capture-and-yield in a list comprehension

Tags: python, iteration, generator, list-comprehension

I'm writing a generator function. I want to know if there's a better (read: more pythonic, ideally with a list comprehension) way to implement something like this:

```
generator = gen()
captures = []
for _ in xrange(x):
    foo = next(generator)
    directories.append(foo['name'])
    yield foo
```

The key here is that I don't want to capture the WHOLE yield- the dictionary returned by `gen()` is large, which is why I'm using a generator. I do need to capture all of the 'name's, though. I feel like there's a way to do this with a list comprehension, but I'm just not seeing it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another / shorter way to do this, but I wouldn't call it more Pythonic:

```
generator = gen()
directories = []
generator_wrapper = (directories.append(foo['name']) or foo 
                         for foo in generator)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `append`, like all mutating methods in Python, always returns `None` so `.append(...) or foo` will always evaluate to `foo`.

That way the whole dictionary is still the result of the generator expression, and you still get lazy evaluation, but the name still gets saved to the `directories` list.

You could also use this method in an explicit `for` loop:

```
for foo in generator:
    yield directories.append(foo['name']) or foo
```

or even just simplify your loop a bit:

```
for foo in generator:
    directories.append(foo['name'])
    yield foo
```

as there is no reason to use an `xrange` just to iterate over the generator (unless you actually want to only iterate some known number of steps in).

Comment: The xrange is because gen() iterates forever, and I don't want the for loop to iterate forever. I could use an islice, though. I think that last one is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the first `x` many elements of the generator? Use `itertools.islice`:

```
directories = [item['name'] for item in itertools.islice(gen(), x)]
```

Comment: This doesn't yield the item, though.